# 500 internal server error......Spatie media throwing file not found exception

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am trying to upload image of the user in laravel using Jquery AJAX post request.rest of form data is added and updated in the table but when the interpreter reaches the line of code where I am adding the image it throws 500 internal server error.

I am send the csrf-token along with the ajax post request

JQUERY CODE:

```
$("#update-info-form").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this),
        url = $form.attr('action');
    $.post(url, {
        firstname: $('#fn').val(),
        lastname: $('#ln').val(),
        partyname: $('#pn').val(),
        email: $('#em').val(),
        phonenumber: $('#pm').val(),
        address1: $('#a1').val(),
        address2: $('#a2').val(),
        type: $('#tp').val(),
        balance: $('#bl').val(),
        userimage: $('#userimage').val(),
        '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()
    }, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#user-info').modal('hide');
        $('#user-info-table').load(window.location.href + ' #user-info-table');
    });
});
```

Laravel Code::

```
if (!is_null($request->userimage)) {
    if (sizeof($mediaItems) > 0) {
        foreach ($mediaItems as $mediaItem) {
            $mediaItem->delete();
        }
    }

    $party->addMedia($request->userimage)
        ->preservingOriginal()
        ->toMediaCollection('avatar');
}
```

Comment: Whenever you need to send a file with ajax req, you have to send it as a FormData, you can check this tutorial https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/access-file-before-upload-using-jquery-ajax/

Comment: Check your error logs (storage/logs/laravel.log), the cause of the 500 error should be listed.

Comment: Thanks solution solved with the help of first commet....thank you so very much